# can't remote desktop to new Azure virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machines, remote-desktop, azure

How can I remote desktop to a virtual windows machine that I just created on Azure?  ..because I want to move a VisualBasic web app and VisualBasic windows app from my old physical Windows server2008 box to the new Azure VM.

Just got new Azure account and added default (quickstart) virtual machine (windows), but now cannot Remote Desktop to it.
Tryied RD to DNS NAME and Public virtual IP (VIP) address, and Internal IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to https://manage.windowsazure.com
2. Select VIRTUAL MACHINES
3. Select row with desired VM
4. Click "CONNECT" located at bottom of page.